# Incircle of a triangle, and circumdcribed circle around the triangle created by the center of the incircle

Tags: geometry

$O$ is the center of the incircle of $\Delta ABC$. If $AB=6$ and $\angle ACB=120^{\circ}$, what is the radius of the circumscribed circle of $\Delta AOB$?

Comment: Aren't there $3$ excircles to a triangle?

Comment: by excircle I mean a circle surrounding the triangle

Comment: That's a **circumcircle**. Excircle is a completely different thing.

Comment: I see the error in my terminology and have fixed it. English is not my first language.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ be the interior angles of the triangle ABC in the usual way, so we know $\gamma=120°$. We have $\sphericalangle BAO = \frac{\alpha}{2}$ and $\sphericalangle ABO = \frac{\beta}{2}$ (center of incircle is the intersection of angle bisectors), hence (sum of inner angles in triangle ABO)

$$ \sphericalangle AOB = 180° -\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2} = 150°,$$

as $\alpha+\beta = 60°$ (sum of inner angles of triangle ABC).

The law of sines in triangle ABO says that $\frac{AB}{\sin \sphericalangle AOB} = 2r$, where $r$ is the radius of the circumscribed circle of ABO. We get $r=6$.